# How to call a function in an event like click in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My problem is when i want to call a function in an event click into two id, the errors is **TypeError: e is undefined**

code here:

```
function slide(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
};
$("#menu-toggle").click(slide());
$("#menu").slide();
```

Comment: `$("#menu-toggle").click(slide);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add an event listener and replace

```
$("#menu-toggle").click(slide());
```

by

```
$("#menu-toggle").on('click', slide);
```

And then when you call click the listener will trigger

But if you want to call the function just one-time use

```
$("#menu-toggle").click(slide);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the `slide` function immediately instead of passing a reference of it to the click handler. Here is what you need:

```
function slide(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
};
$("#menu-toggle").click(slide);
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to call the function , 
you just pass it without `()`

```
function slide(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
};


$("#menu-toggle").click(slide);
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e){
  // here you can call however many functions you want. 
  slide(e)
  console.log("#menu-toggle clicked")
  // ...
});
$("#menu-toggle").click($("#menu").slide);
```